# Ошибка установки pycurl

Tags: python, linux, pip

Использую в своем коде grab, с помощью него осуществляется проверка прокси на валидность. Собственно при запуске программы вылетает ошибка о том что невозможно импортировать pycurl. Пытаюсь его установить и получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
WARNING:vext:Skipped adding nonexistant path: /usr/share/sip

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pip-install-9igns52a/pycurl/setup.py", line 223, in configure_unix
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config': 'curl-config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-9igns52a/pycurl/setup.py", line 913, in <module>
    ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-9igns52a/pycurl/setup.py", line 582, in get_extension
    ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-9igns52a/pycurl/setup.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.configure()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-9igns52a/pycurl/setup.py", line 227, in configure_unix
    raise ConfigurationError(msg)
__main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config': 'curl-config'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-install-9igns52a/pycurl/
```

Answer (score 0):

Для установки pycurl в Вашем происходит сборка из исходников. Для неё необходимы компилятор и dev файлы от libcurl.

curl-config можно [найти в пакете](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libcurl4-openssl-dev) , но лучше поставить уже собраннуюю версию из пакетов python3-pycurl или python-pycurl.